# AngularJS ui router problems with substate routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Really no idea what's happening here, i've done this thing milions of times before.

The following configuration causes the *root state* to be executed even when the route is matching with the substate.

```
module.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('apps-neo',{
        url: '/apps/neo/',
        template: '<a ui-sref="apps-neo.a({id: 1})">test</a>',
        controller: function(){
            console.log('parent controller')
        },
        navbar: 'apps'
    }).state('apps-neo.a',{
        url: 'a/:id',
        template: 'a',
        controller: function($stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams.id)
        },
        navbar: 'apps'
    });
}
```

**Case 1 `GET /apps/neo/`**

I get the parent state activated, which is correct. Console logs *parent controller* and view shows the *test* link.

**Case 2 `GET /apps/neo/a/1`**

I still get the parent state activated, which is weird. Console logs *parent controller* and view shows the *test* link.

---

If i change to the following, basically removing states hierarchy, everything works as expected.

```
module.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('apps-neo',{
        url: '/apps/neo/',
        template: '<a ui-sref="apps-neo.a({id: 1})">test</a>',
        controller: function(){
            console.log('parent controller')
        },
        navbar: 'apps'
    }).state('apps-neo-a',{ // <------ do not make this state nest from previous
        url: '/apps/neo/a/:id',
        template: 'a',
        controller: function($stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams.id)
        },
        navbar: 'apps'
    });
}
```

**Case 1 `GET /apps/neo/`**

I get the `apps-neo` state activated, which is correct. Console logs *parent controller*.

**Case 2 `GET /apps/neo/a/1`**

I get the `apps-neo-a` state activated, which is correct. Console logs *1* and the view shows *a*.

---

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another `ui-view` in your parent state, in order for nested states to render.

For instance:

```
template: `<a ui-sref="apps-neo.a({id: 1})">test</a>
           <hr/>
           <div ui-view></div>`,
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not declaring a ui-view in the parent template.

When the application is in a particular state—when a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well.

Child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view.

enter code here

```
module.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('apps-neo',{
    url: '/apps/neo/',
    template: '<a ui-sref="apps-neo.a({id: 1})">test</a><div ui-view</div>',
    controller: function(){
        console.log('parent controller')
    },
    navbar: 'apps'
}).state('apps-neo-a',{ // <------ do not make this state nest from previous
    url: 'a/:id',
    template: 'a',
    controller: function($stateParams){
        console.log($stateParams.id)
    },
    navbar: 'apps'
});
```

}